# Selection-Box is drawn higher than click position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [this npm package, react-selectable-fast](http://valerybugakov.github.io/react-selectable-fast/) (See the demo to get a better understanding of what I am talking about). When a user selects something, there is the dotted lined box which shows where on the screen you've drawn the selection-box.

In the example code, they seem to give their selection box an outline like so:

```
.selectable-selectbox {
  z-index: 9000;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  background: none;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}
```

I have copied their stylesheet to have the same kind of selection box outline. But it doesn't start at the right point. My selection box is drawn way higher. What might be the reason? Is there anything in the React/JS code I need to consider?

Comment: Have you set the parent `div` to `position: relative;`? The `selectable-selectbox` is positioned absolute relative tot the first parent that has `position: relative`. `body` tag always has `position: relative`.

Comment: omg that's it! I just tried that, and it works. i just don't understand why this isn't in the code of the `<SelectableGroup/>` component? I would have NEVER figured out that I would have to set this myself! Thank you so much